# App Engine can't find file when deploying

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I am making an app that need access to files in my Google Cloud Buckets.
I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6AyODLdA6M) tutorial to get access to my files.
The tutorial says you need to use the "service account key page"-json file to get access to the buckets, like this:

```python
storage_client= storage.Client.from_service_account_json("/home/Project/red-freedom-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX.json")
```

The Json-file is stored in the same folder as the main.py and the app.yaml files.
The program runs smoothly when i run it locally, however when i deploy it, i get:

```python
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/home/Project/red-freedom-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX.json"
```

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an absolute path to the `.json` file based on your local filesystem, but on App Engine this needs to be a different path.

Instead, you can use a relative path from the file you're trying to create the client in:

```py
import os

current_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path_to_service_account_json = os.path.join(current_directory, 'red-freedom-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX.json')
storage_client= storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path_to_service_account_json)
```